# React Native Flat List resize item

Tags: android, css, react-native, flexbox, react-native-flatlist

```
    <FlatList
      data={['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']}
      numColumns={4}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <Button title={item} />
      )}
    />
```

How can i resize the button such that the 4 buttons on the same row takes up the entire screen width?
`width: "25%"` or `flex: 1` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you applied those styles width: "25%" or flex: 1, because you cant provide styles to Button component directly according to the react-native docs. So you need to wrap the **Button** component in View and apply styles to that View.

BTW in your case **both width: '25%' and flex: 1 works**, below is the code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet,FlatList,Button } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <FlatList
      data={['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']}
      numColumns={4}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View style={{flex:1,height:100}} >
         <Button title={item} />
        </View>
      )}
    />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

snack demo - https://snack.expo.io/SkidXdPDZ